# View based tableview and animating

Tags: macos, core-animation, nstableview, appkit

I recently switched to using a view based tableview as it greatly simplifies a lot of my code, loving it so far.

In the sample apps mentioned and demo'd in the session video of WWDC 2011, they have some cool animations which are rather simple to implement. I am however populating the tableview using my own controller / model and therefore not using cocoa bindings. I would like to know how I would achieve a 'fade in' animation using the view based tableview whenever I add an item.

Currently doing the following:

- model will update: [tableView beginUpdates]
- [tableView insertItemsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:someIndex] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationFadeIn];
- update the model
- [tableView endUpdates]

Comment: What result are you getting? What is you question?

Comment: No animation, my question is how I achieve the animation without using cocoa bindings.